# Posix shared memory synchronisation when only one process is writing

Tags: c++, c, posix, shared-memory

Do we need to synchronise memory access if only one process is writing and other is reading from Posix shared memory?

For example:
I want to store a structure of Item in shared memory, and there are two processes A and B has mapped this structure in their address space.
Only process A is updating the Item price and process B is reading the corresponding item price when needed.

```
struct Item
{
    char name[20];
    double price;
};
```

Comment: Yes you do in general. Otherwise the reader may read inconsistent data if the writer is in the middle of updating part of the shared mem.

Comment: Yes.  Consider the writer is writing a string that is 100 bytes long - overwriting the string that was there before.  Now the writer writes the first 50 bytes and then the OS decides that the time slice is finished and schedules the reader - it notices there is new data and reads all 100 bytes (half new and half old).  Then after reading the whole thing the OS reschedules the writer - and if finishes writing the other 50 bytes.  Of course if the data is one character long there is no problem.  Even 4 bytes might be ok depending on the machine - but you can't guarantee it.

Comment: thanks @kaylum I was referring [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) and it appears OS ensure atomic write.

Comment: @rishirai  Not all computers have an atomic test and set - but I am pretty sure any CPU with multiple cores will...